Passing a password securely as an maven argument from jenkins
I'm running a job in jenkins that is taking password argument and passing it in a pipeline to start a maven process with that given password argument. That is obviously not very secure way of handling passwords as it's visible as a string. My idea of handling it is to use credentials plugin in jenkins but have no clue how could i possible pass this credentials object to maven securely.
I'm pasting a snipped of my pipeline to better display what i'm trying to achieve and show what jenkins plugin I'm trying to use, if you have any other suggestions of how i could securely pass a password from jenkins to maven I'm all ears
stage('Run') {
   withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'test', usernameVariable: 'USERNAME', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
      mvn test    }


Where do you need the username/password in Maven?

i need to pass it into my java code, i'll be using it to login with selenium
